# mp3 audio files in Javascript

Tags: javascript, audio

How would I properly put a mp3 file into my javascript program. By this I mean can I just type the name of any mp3 file I have saved on my computer or does it have to be mentioned somewhere else in the code.

```
var sound1 = new Audio('file1.mp3');
```

So if I declared the variable "sound" to play file1 do I have to tell the program what file1 is. If so, how would I do so.

Comment: Are you running this on localhost?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `file:///`, and then use the file path of your mp3 file

```
var sound1 = new Audio('file:///C:/Users/user/file1.mp3');
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
var sound1 = new Audio('file1.mp3');
```

Whit

```
var sound1 = new Audio('http://example.com/sub/file.mp3');
```

While you want the adress to be the adress to you'r mp3 file on your server.

You might write a shorted version of the adress if the file on sub folder like this:

```
var sound1 = new Audio('/sub/file.mp3');
```